# Allow null in JSON schema from Pydantic

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

I'm trying to allow null in the JSON schema for this object:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional

class NextSong(BaseModel):
    song_title: Optional[str] = ...
```

but the schema which results is as follows:

```json
{
    "title": "NextSong",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "song_title": {
            "title": "Song Title",
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": ["song_title"]
}
```

The resulting schema isn't allowing null for the value of song_title, which isn't as intended, but I'm not sure how else to specify that null is allowed, but that the field is still required.

Comment: Have you seen the [issue #1270](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/1270)?

Comment: Can you show your complete model ?

Comment: The model shown is complete. Thanks for linking the issue, that helps.

Comment: See this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73261442/17865804) as well

Answer (score 1):

I think you need OpenAPI nullable flag. It should change the schema and set nullable flag, but this field still will be required.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import Optional

class NextSong(BaseModel):
    song_title: Optional[str] = Field(..., nullable=True)
```

Resulting schema:

```json
{
    "title": "NextSong",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "song_title": {
            "title": "Song Title",
            "nullable": true,
            "type": "string"
            }
        },
    "required": ["song_title"]
}
```