# How to exclude Optional unset values from a Pydantic model using FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, optional-parameters

I have this model:

```
class Text(BaseModel):
    id: str
    text: str = None


class TextsRequest(BaseModel):
    data: list[Text]
    n_processes: Union[int, None]
```

So I want to be able to take requests like:

```
{"data": ["id": "1", "text": "The text 1"], "n_processes": 8}
```

and

```
{"data": ["id": "1", "text": "The text 1"]}.
```

Right now in the second case I get

```
{'data': [{'id': '1', 'text': 'The text 1'}], 'n_processes': None}
```

using this code:

```
app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/make_post/", response_model_exclude_none=True)
async def create_graph(request: TextsRequest):
    input_data = jsonable_encoder(request)
```

So how can I exclude `n_processes` here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

###### Since Pydantic >= 2.0 deprecates model.dict() use [`model.model_dump(...)`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/serialization/#modelmodel_dump) instead.

---

You can use `exclude_none` param of Pydantic's [model.dict(...)](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#modeldict):

```
class Text(BaseModel):
    id: str
    text: str = None


class TextsRequest(BaseModel):
    data: list[Text]
    n_processes: Optional[int]


request = TextsRequest(**{"data": [{"id": "1", "text": "The text 1"}]})
print(request.dict(exclude_none=True))
```

**Output:**

```
{'data': [{'id': '1', 'text': 'The text 1'}]}
```

Also, it's more idiomatic to write `Optional[int]` instead of `Union[int, None]`.

Comment: Would disagree with your last statement. Union is closer to python 3.10 syntax than Optional, but that’s just my opinion.

Comment: Pydantic >= 2.0 deprecates `model.dict()`. As Eapen Jose wrote, use `model_dump()`.

Answer (score 7):

Pydantic provides the following arguments for exporting models using the [`model.dict(...)`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/exporting_models/#modeldict) method. **Update**: the `model.dict(...)` was deprecated (but still supported) and replaced by **[`model.model_dump(...)`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/serialization/#modelmodel_dump)**. Those parameters are as follows:

> `exclude_unset`: whether fields which were not explicitly set when
> creating the model should be excluded from the returned dictionary;
> default `False`
>
> `exclude_none`: whether fields which are equal to None should be
> excluded from the returned dictionary; default `False`

Since you are refering to excluding optional **unset** parameters, you can use the first  method (i.e., `exclude_unset`). This is useful when one would like to exclude a parameter *only* if it has not been set to either some value or `None`.

The `exclude_none` argument, however, ignores that fact that an attribute may have been intentionally set to `None`, and hence, excludes it from the returned dictionary.

Example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List, Union

class Text(BaseModel):
    id: str
    text: str = None

class TextsRequest(BaseModel):
    data: List[Text]    # in Python 3.9+ you can use:  data: list[Text]
    n_processes: Union[int, None] = None

t = TextsRequest(**{'data': [{'id': '1', 'text': 'The text 1'}], 'n_processes': None})
print(t.model_dump(exclude_none=True))
#> {'data': [{'id': '1', 'text': 'The text 1'}]}
print(t.model_dump(exclude_unset=True))
#> {'data': [{'id': '1', 'text': 'The text 1'}], 'n_processes': None}
```

#### Excluding `Unset` or `None` parameters from the response

If what you needed is excluding `Unset` or `None` parameters from the endpoint's response, without necessarily calling `model.dict(...)` (or, in Pydantic V2 `model.model_dump(...)`) inside the endpoint on your own, you could instead use the endpoint's *decorator* parameter `response_model_exclude_unset` or `response_model_exclude_none` (see the [relevant documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/#use-the-response_model_exclude_unset-parameter) and related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75115378/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71846619/17865804)). To achieve that, FastAPI, behind the scenes, uses the aforementioned `model.dict(...)` (or, in Pydantic V2 `model.model_dump(...)`) method with its `exclude_unset` or `exclude_none` parameter.

Examples:

```py
@app.post("/create", response_model_exclude_unset=True)
async def create_graph(t: TextsRequest):
    return t
```

or

```py
@app.post("/create", response_model_exclude_none=True)
async def create_graph(t: TextsRequest):
    return t
```

### About Optional Parameters

Using `Union[int, None]` is the same as using `Optional[int]` (both are equivalent). The most important part, however, to make a parameter optional is the part `= None`.

As per [FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/) (see admonition **Note** and **Info** in the link provided):

**Note**

> FastAPI will know that the value of `q` is not required because of the
> default value `= None`.
>
> The `Union` in `Union[str, None]` will allow your editor to give you
> better support and detect errors.

**Info**

> Have in mind that the most important part to make a parameter optional
> is the part: `= None`, as it will use that `None` as the default value, and that way make the
> parameter **not required**.
>
> The `Union[str, None]` part allows your editor to provide better
> support, **but it is not what tells FastAPI** that this parameter is
> **not required**.

Hence, regardless of the option you may choose to use, if it is not followed by the `= None` part, FastAPI won't know that the value of the parameter is *optional*, and hence, the user will **have to provide** some value for it. One can also check that through the auto-generated API docs at http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs, where the `parameter` or `request body` will appear as a **`Required`** field.

For example, any of the below would **require** the user to pass some `body` content in their request for the `TextsRequest` model:

```py
@app.post("/upload")
def upload(t: Union[TextsRequest, None]):
    pass

@app.post("/upload")
def upload(t: Optional[TextsRequest]):
    pass
```

If, however, the above `TextsRequest` definitions were **succeeded by** `= None`, for example:

```py
@app.post("/upload")
def upload(t: Union[TextsRequest, None] = None):
    pass

@app.post("/upload")
def upload(t: Optional[TextsRequest] = None):
    pass
    
@app.post("/upload")
def upload(t: TextsRequest = None): # this should work as well
    pass
```

the parameter (or body) would be **optional**, as `= None` would tell FastAPI that this parameter is **not required**.

#### In Python 3.10+

The [good news](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/python-types/#using-union-or-optional) is that in Python 3.10 and above, you don't have to worry about names like `Optional` and `Union`, as you can simply use the vertical bar `|` (also called bitwise or operator, but that meaning is not relevant here) to define an *optional* parameter (or simply, unions of types). **However**, the same rule applies to this option as well, i.e., you would still need to add the `= None` part, if you would like to make the parameter *optional* (as demonstrated in the example given below).

Example:

```py
@app.post("/upload")
def upload(t: TextsRequest | None = None):
    pass
```

Comment: The FastAPI link and Pydantic link are both dead

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. They have been updated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `response_model_exlclude_none` you can use `response_model_exclude_unset`

```
app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/make_post/", response_model_exclude_unset=True)
async def create_graph(request: TextsRequest):
    input_data = jsonable_encoder(request)
```