# Python API Patch updates all fields instead of just the given

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

So my issue is when creating a patch request to `post` which will update `title` and `content` but when sending, the patch request updates all optional fields to the defaults:

`post`- it's class:

```
class Post(BaseModel):
  title: str
  content: str
  published: bool = True
  rating: Optional[bool] = None
```

`post` stored in memory:

```
[{"title": "title",
  "content": "stuff", 
  "published": False,
  "rating": True,
  "id": 1}]
```

json sent:

```
{
"title": "updated title",
"content": "stuffyy"
}
```

`post` received:

```
{
"data": {
    "title": "updated title",
    "content": "stuffyy",
    "published": true,
    "rating": null,
    "id": 1
   }
}
```

and the python code:

```
@app.patch("/posts/{id}")
def update_post(id: int, post: Post):
    index = find_index_post(id)
    if index == None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail=f"post with id: '{id}' does not exist, hence cannot be updated")
    post_dict = post.dict()
    post_dict['id'] = id
    my_posts[index] = post_dict
    return {"data": post_dict}
```

probably out of my depth here

Comment: You would need to use Pydantic's `exclude_unset=True`, e.g., `post_dict = post.dict(exclude_unset=True)`. Please have a look at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73261442/17865804) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **exclude** those fields that are not required to partially update(patching), currently on your `Post` schema `published`, `rating` has default values like `True(true)` and `None(null)` because you are referring **post: Post** here `def update_post(id: int, post: Post):`

```
class Post(BaseModel):
  title: str
  content: str
  published: bool = True        #  <--------default to true
  rating: Optional[bool] = None #  <--------default to null
```

So you can do this way with `exclude` while making post to the dictionary.

```
post_dict = post.dict(exclude_unset=True)
```

**OR**

```
post_dict = post.dict(exclude={'published', 'rating'})
```

Comment: this does work in not updating the fields excluded, but it does this by deleting the fields not given - any work around?

Answer (score 0):

You want `PATCH`, not `POST` to only update the fields explicitly included. `POST` creates a whole new object and overwrites with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to patch only limited fields in a post object, you may create another class that only includes the fields that you want to allow users to update.

Example:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
class PatchModelForPost(BaseModel):
  title: str
  content: str

@app.patch("/posts/{id}")
def update_post(id: int, post: PatchModelForPost):
```