# Pydantic returns 'field required (type=value_error.missing)' on an Optional field with a custom model

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, fastapiusers

I'm trying to build a custom field in Fastapi-users pydantic schema as follows:

```py
class UserRead(schemas.BaseUser[uuid.UUID]):
    twitter_account: Optional['TwitterAccount']
```

On UserRead validation Pydantic returns

```py
field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

on every field in `'TwitterAccount'` `schema.update_forward_refs()` is called at the end.

`TwitterAccount` itself has required fields and making them optional isn't an acceptable workaround. I notices I could make `Optional[List['TwitterAccount']]` and it will work, but that's a bit silly.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example and the full error message.

Comment: Related answer can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73261442/17865804).

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question because I do not think it should have been closed as a duplicate, per the consensus [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292329/does-the-same-answer-imply-that-the-questions-should-be-closed-as-duplicate); overlapping answers do not imply duplicate questions.

Answer (score 14):

`Optional` is a bit misleading here. What it means technically means is that `twitter_account` can be a `TwitterAccount` or `None`, but it is still a required argument. To make it truly optional (as in, it doesn't have to be provided), you must provide a default:

```py
class UserRead(schemas.BaseUser[uuid.UUID]):
    twitter_account: Optional['TwitterAccount'] = None
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Unlike every other type annotation, the union with `None` **always** implicitly has the default value `None`. Thus, it is  **not** a required argument. The error must stem from something else.

Comment: @Chris Try this: `class Foo(BaseModel):  x: Optional[int]`; `print(Foo())` That is the Pydantic side of things. That is why I said, the error must stem from something else, something to do with how FastAPI handles it.

Comment: It seems that an explicit default value is not required by pydantic since it released a new major version (v2). The example by @DaniilFajnberg above now results in

```console
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Foo
x
  Field required [type=missing, input_value={}, input_type=dict]
```

Comment: Relevant documentation: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/migration/#required-optional-and-nullable-fields

Comment: @AbidH.Mujtaba, this explicit default _can_ still be required in v2, if using `pydantic.dataclasses`.